# `Object` vs `extend` in js console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I couldn't find any clear answer, so what's the difference between `Object`type and `extend` type in JavaScript?

In **AngularJS**, when I consoled `$state`:

```
console.log($state)
console.log($state.$current.parent)
```

I got the output as:

[image: $state and $state.$current.parent]

As you can see, the $state is interpreted as an Object where the latter is an extend?

I needed the parent name of current state, so I was planning to take it from the `self.name` object of `$state.$current.parent`. Is that okay? Or should I keep out of `extend`?

Comment: Please update your json in below website and share the result url so tht we can check

Comment: http://myjson.com/

Comment: @Dilip No. All relevant parts need to be posted in the question, not put at some external storage. Although I don't see how JSON is relevant here at all.

Comment: @Dilip Er.. I couldn't stringify the $state.     `console.log(JSON.stringify($state.$current.parent))` returns error `converting circular structure to JSON`. basically it's a big object with so much nested children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They both are objects.** Chrome's console additionally tells you their type. The first one it's a generic object whereas the second one is still an object, but named instead.

Here's how you can create named objects very easily:

```
function NamedObject() { this.aProperty = 'something'; }
var namedObject = new NamedObject();
```

[image]

Generic objects are created like this:

```
var genericObject = { aProperty: 'something' };
```

[image]

In your specific case, `uiRouter` uses [`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) internally. If you were to assign a name to [this anonymous function here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/ef5ce80fa6ec8a2c6a87cf1cf1c5809e1950af11/src/common.js#L16) you'd see how *extend* will be renamed to the function's name.

Comment: Oh.. so this is not related to any kind of inheritance and all, right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends. And I suppose it's okay to read the properties of the named objects?

Comment: Nope, it's unrelated. It's, more or less, a bug from `uiRouter`. I'll edit my post in just a few to showcase this.